# How do I get Chatgpt to stop talking in my TTS bot at the right moment?

Tags: python, text-to-speech, openai-api

I am extremely new to coding, this is my first ever coding project, I am using Python script for this project.
I have managed to code up something where I can speak to chatgpt and it can return back TTS to me which works great. What I am struggling with is that I have tried setting the tokens to 40 and even 100 but when the chatgpt speaks it will either:

(I apologise for the examples in advance)

1. It will say a great sentence but then go say something else and be cut off example:
   **ChatGPT:** *The grass is green and hasn't been mowed in a while and*

or

2. Will continue the sentence in the next prompt

**Me:** "*Do you know anything about cows?*
**ChatGpt:** *there are flowers that are pink. Yes there are some awesome cows I can tell you about*

Is there something I can put in my code to tell it, once you get to a completed sentence stop and answer my next question. I hope the code I have supplied is the right bit for someone to help me. Thank you

```
# Sentence chunking function
def chunk_text_into_sentences(text):
    sentences = text.split('. ')
    return sentences   

# Main Mic, Chat History
def main():
    recording = False
    paused = False

    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("m"):
            recording = True
            print("Microphone ON. Say your question...")
            while recording:
                if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):  # Pause
                    paused = True
                    print("Bot paused.")
                    while keyboard.is_pressed("p"):  # Wait for 'p' key to be released
                        time.sleep(0.1)
                if not paused:
                    with sr.Microphone() as source:
                        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
                        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
                        try:
                            transcription = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                            print("Transcription:", transcription) 
                            if transcription.lower() == "n":
                                recording = False
                                print("Microphone OFF.")
                            else:
                                text = transcription
                                if text:
                                    print("You said:", text)
                                    response = generate_response(text) 
                                    print("Response:", response)
                                    text_to_speech_elevenlabs(response)
                                    chat_history.append({"role": "user", "content": text})
                                    chat_history.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})
                        except sr.UnknownValueError:
                            pass

                if keyboard.is_pressed("u"):
                    paused = False
                    print("Bot resumed.")
                    while keyboard.is_pressed("u"):  # Wait for 'u' key to be released
                        time.sleep(0.1)

def generate_response(prompt, max_tokens=40):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
        messages=chat_history,
        max_tokens=max_tokens,
        n=1,
        stop=None,
        temperature=1,
    )
    return response.choices[0].message['content']
```

I have tried changing the token size, changing the max_tokens, I have put in the code for sentence fundamentals and tried removing it and nothing has changed, only got more words and description from chatgpt.

Comment: Did you ask ChatGPT for a solution?

Comment: Yeah I did and it came up with that sentence fundamental script, which still didn't help and suggested to add 100 tokens, which i did. Did not fix it